# Spring Java Format + IntelliJ + chain method call wrapping

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I'm using Spring Java Format plugin for IntelliJ to standardize my code style. I'm also using Save Action Plugin to format the code anytime I save it. I'm trying do find which rule makes chain method calls to be joined.

For instance, if I format my code like this:

```java
method()
    .call1()
    .call2()
    .call3()
```

When it is saved, it is formatted like this:

```java
method().call1().call2()
    .call3()
------------------------^ right margin limit
```

Assuming the third method call transpose the right margin limit.

I would like to keep the wrapped version without automatic join.
Does anybody faced the same problem?

**Edit1:**

I've just realized that the coded is joined together by `mvn spring-javaformat:apply`. So the problem is not related to IntelliJ Spring Java Format Plugin.

I'm still trying to identify what Checkstyle rule is doing that.

Comment: Does it happen with Spring JavaFormat plug-in disabled? What are your IntelliJ IDEA code style settings for the chained method calls?

Comment: When Spring Java Format plugin is triggered by Save Action Plugin, it keeps the code as I want, although, when I ctrl shif f (I use Eclipse keymap) to format my code, or run the Maven goal to format, it joins everything together.

Comment: Please [check this screenshot with the relevant configuration](https://i.imgur.com/4tkajMy.png).

Comment: Yes, I already did the same configuration on my IDEA.

Comment: You may have multiple formatters enabled and it's hard to say which one triggers this behavior. Try the clean IDE install with no third-party plug-ins.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I've just realized that when I run 'mvn spring-javaformat:apply` the wrapped code is joined. So, I think is something related to spring-javaformat definitions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the default code style for Spring Java Format. And although it is "not generally configurable", there is an escape hatch to disable formatting entirely. This feature is mentioned in the docs here: [Disabling formatting for blocks of code](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat/tree/9d49e3786c919c38f460e34841fdd31a539fef68#disabling-formatting-for-blocks-of-code).

Aligning chained method calls an ideal use case for this:

```java
// @formatter:off
method()
    .call1()
    .call2()
    .call3()
// @formatter:on
```

Many of the official Spring projects do this as well. For example:

Source: [spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-secure-jersey/src/main/java/smoketest/secure/jersey/SecurityConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0818f27f44317c52f66b9f0e7030fa8fcb7a92f0/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-secure-jersey/src/main/java/smoketest/secure/jersey/SecurityConfiguration.java#L43-L51)

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health", "info")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint().excluding(MappingsEndpoint.class)).hasRole("ACTUATOR")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```